# API confirmation of success other than using response status

Tags: javascript, reactjs, try-catch, jsx

So I am confused about industry-standard implementation. I feel this is a hacky way the way I am doing it right now

I want to display an error message whenever there is an actual error and display a failure message whenever the server return a nonsuccess status

The problem here is when there is an actual error on assignUser() it returns the error and this does not trigger the catch of the first function, so it is handled by the else statement instead and shows a failure message while it is an actual error.
I tried to use throw new Error("error) in the catch of assignUser() but the same issue.

The second concern I have is regarding `(200 >= status <300)` is there a simpler way to check a successful operation other than checking the status which can be 200, 204 ...?

```
  try {
        let status = assignUser(user);
        if (status >= 200 && status < 300) {
          notify.show("message success");
        } else {
          notify.show("message failure");
        }
      } catch (e) {
        notify.show("message error");
      }


 export async function assignUser(user) {
  try {......
    return resp.status;
  } catch (e) {
    return e;
  }
}
```

Comment: `200 >= status <300)` you can't do comparison like that. It will accept anything larger than 200, even 400, use `200 >= status && status < 300)`

Comment: `assignUser`  doesn't trigger catch because you already caught the error. Just remove error handling from `assignUser` or throw another error in catch

Comment: sorry that's what I do, I wrote the post in a hurry I am fixing that

Comment: @KonradLinkowski Ah that's true, I should not try to catch it there, however, I tried to throw another error inside the catch and it did not work.

Comment: How do you throw an error?

Answer (score 2):

I assume assignUser function is making an api call using fetch. So if you are not using the then catch method to resolve the promise, then the assignUser function has to be an async function.

```
async function assignUser(user) {
  try {
    const jsonRes = await fetch(url);
    if(!jsonRes.ok) {
       notify.show("message failure");
    } else {
       notify.show("message success");
       const result = await jsonRes.json();
       return result;
    }
  } catch (e) {
    notify.show("message error");
  }
}
```

Here you don't need another function to check the status and all
and instead of checking with the status code you can use the response.ok property.

Hope this helps
Thanks

Comment: I didn't know about response.ok, thank you and yes it's async function what the solution in that case?

Comment: Async function always returns a promise, the return value will be the resolved value of that promise, and if we are throwing an error from the function, then it will be the rejected value of the promise. So here if you just need to show the message only, you can call assignUser, but if you need the result from the api then you need another async function or you can use then and catch to get the value.
using an immediately invoked function is also a good idea.
(async () => {
   try{
    const result = await assignUser(user);
} catch(e) {
     console.log("error");
  }
})()

Comment: I didn't really grasp what you wanted to stay, can you make it an answer? thanks